# Unable to Send CDATA in PHP Soap Clinet

Tags: php, soap

i am sending the soap request, and getting proper response from server also. but unable to send CDATA as string. the method type are object and string

```
class clsSecurity {
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->fullname= 'fullname';
    $this->username = 'username';
    $this->password = 'password';
    $this->ip = 'XX.XX.XX.XX';
    $this->request = 'XXX';
}
```

}

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://wsdlurl?WSDL",['trace' => 1]);
$contact = new clsSecurity();


 $par = "<![CDATA[<Availability>
<seat>D</seat>
<room>O</room>
<access>N</access>
</Availability>]]>";

$params = array(
  'objSecurity' => $contact,
'avalibility'=>$par
);
$response = $client->__soapCall("roomAvailability", array($params));
echo "<>" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "<>";
```

I am unable to send the `availability` as string, the first parameter should be obj and second will be string.
after `$clinet->__getType();`

```
Availability { clsSecurity objSecurity; string roomAvailability; }
```

Comment: You may try to execute `print_r($client->__getTypes(), true);` and get information about the `roomAvailability` parameters. If it's possible, post it here.

Comment: @Zhorov , i updated the answer with getTypes() response